# How to get Icecast absolute streaming time

Tags: html, audio, streaming, metadata, icecast

I am trying to get the absolute time of an Icecast audio stream using HTML and Javacript.

Right now I am using an `<audio>` tag with a `<source>` pointing the the stream URL, but when I open the page and press play, the track current time always starts from 0.

I would like to know the absolute track time, for example:

- stream started at 12:00 and I open the page at 12:45 -> the current time is 00:45:00 (45 minutes)

I tried to extract audio `metadata` and get the track duration, but it shows Infinity.

HINT: when the stream is played from VLC, the time is shown correctly, so I suppose there should be a way to achieve this also on a web page.

Comment: I don't think the browser media APIs expose such information. If this is for a particular Icecast server that you control you could make out of band requests, but if this should be generic then there is unfortunately no easy way that I know of.

Comment: Yes, I have control of the Icecast server. I am trying to implement a sort of auto sync between devices, that's why I need to know the exact track time. Retrieving the information with other requests would result in an approximate absolute time. I am wondering how VLC handles this since it's receiving the same HTTP stream

Comment: If you require sub second sync, then Icecast is the wrong tool. Drift, even up to 10s is normal and expected, especially if you don't have 100% client control. If you need close sync, look at things like SIP (Jitsi?) or webRTC.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, could you please explain better what you mean with "drift"?

Comment: Complex topic, but mostly driven by soundcard frequency instability leading to different speed of playback and thus players on different computers naturally drifting apart.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will consider using a different implementation. But regarding my question, how does VLC know that piece of information?

Comment: @SimonePozzoli The timing information is in the stream container, like Ogg or WebM.  You can't access it directly via HTMLMediaElements, but technically you could do this yourself via MediaSource Extensions.  You can actually sort of synchronize multiple devices by adjusting the `playbackRate` to drift them in-sync.  But, it will never be perfect.

Comment: @Brad would you mind giving an example of how to use Media Source Extension? I'm sorry but I'm new to frontend programming, any help is much appreciated. Regarding how to sync devices I was thinking to use websockets to send/receive timestamps and keep a reference time on the server (WS helps me because I want to create some sort of "sync room" for users). Then I could change the `playbackRate` to keep them sync as you suggested.

Comment: @SimonePozzoli MediaSource Extensions can be quite complicated.  This is probably a bit out of grasp right now if you're just starting, but you can read up more here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#examples